# How can we construct an example of isometric linear operator?

Tags: functional-analysis

How  can  we construct   an example of isometric linear operator $T: H \rightarrow  H$ which is not
unitary but maps the Hilbert space $H$ onto a proper closed subspace of $H.$

My attempt  I found this  proof here [Prob. 9, Sec. 3.10 in Kreyszig's functional analysis book: The image of ann isometric non-unitary operator on a Hilbert space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1314201/557708)

But in the given link answer   there is  no  example .

My Question is  that  how  can  we take  an  example  that satisfied the  given above statement

Comment: Try exploring the space $\ell^2$, the square summable sequences. Try some linear maps that keep all the same terms of the given sequence, while introducing some $0$s.

Answer (score 0):

Credit : user780985

take $f : l^2 \rightarrow  l^2$  defined by $f( x_1,x_2,......) = (0 ,x_1,x_2,x_3,...)$

where $x= (x_n) \in l^2$

This is not unitary  since $f(x_1,x_2,......) \notin (1, 1/2,1/3 ....)$

i mean to say that $f$ is not onto

lastly used this logics

Unitary = onto + isometry